# Dynamic redirection when saving a magento product

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm running magento 1.5.1.0 at the moment, and so far I've managed to get an edit button created for each product inside the "Category Products" section of each category. My problem is coming in whenever the user hits the save button after editing a product.

Basically, I would like to be able to set the back or save button to redirect back to the category page if the category page is the referrer, otherwise I would like it to go back to the "manage products" page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to rewrite the product edit and product save post actions. In the first, you'll need to stash the originating category and (if set) pass it on to the rewritten save post action, where you can test and set `_redirect()` with the appropriate params. For examples of controller rewrites, see the config in Mage_Index under the  node.